# how to get previously selected rows of a bootstrap dataTable while searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have used a bootstrap DataTable to show data. At the same time i have a HTML checkbox as a column of that dataTable. I have a submit button to get the selected checkbox's value to do some stuff. I am fetching the following problem while select checkboxes under searching.

[image]

When i select all checkboxes and Click **Save** button I got all the values. It works as my expectation.

But Unexpected occures when i search via built-in search box of bootstrap dataTable.Here is the pictorial view

[image]

In this case when i press **Save** i got just the two value though all other values are still selected. **How can i get all the selected values while searching**

Here is my jquery code of **Save** button of getting the checkboxes value

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
    var vals = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            vals += "," + checkboxes[i].value;
        }
    }
    ....
    //Other stuff
    ....
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Non of this has anything to do with bootstrap other than for style. You need to work within the DataTables plugin api

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can work directly on your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my job done like this

```
  var table = $('#tblReportList').dataTable();
```

When i was searching through dataTable, i was getting just the selected values matching the search criteria. But the previously selected values was disappeared. To get the previously selected value i used the following code...

```
 table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
     if (!$.contains(document, this)) {
      if (this.checked) {
        previousVal = previousVal + ',' + this.value;
       }
     }
 });
```

Now, for getting the selected values of search I used the previous code posted before. And that was

```
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
 var vals = "";
 for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        vals += "," + checkboxes[i].value;
     }
 }
```

So all selected checkbox's values are

```
var allValues=previousVal+vals;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing a search, it is going to check only for the rows, that satisfy the given criteria. So your search logic works like this

```
if(searchCriteria==true)
{
showValue
}
```

Even if you had previously selected values it won't be showing all of them, because they don't satisfy the given criteria. Now in this case when you click on Save, it is taking only those rows in the datatable which are checked and satisfy the given criteria, as per your java script.

Now if you still wish, that all selected values should be taken in, there is one way you can try, put the selected values in some kind of List or Set, and place the list object in session. So everytime you click on Save, you can retrieve the List from the session. But I really don't see why you would want to do it, unless you need to retrieve the selected values every time.